# Autodesk extractor shows error #9 - No viewable content

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-navisworks

For some reason Autodesk extractor throws Error #9 when trying to preview & download extracted models:

https://extract.autodesk.io/

[image]

This happens with every Navisworks model we are trying to upload.

We are relying heavily on the extractor in our product, and it seems like there's nothing else we can do.

We also tried the desktop .NET extractor but without success.

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce the same issue on my side with nwd file, and this should be a problem with extract io, the same urn works well if I open it in my other app or A360. I did a quick look at the extract code, the error happens on line 139(    Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load (urn, onDocumentLoaded, onError)) of views/explore.ejs, the urn failed to be loaded. I am busy with a conference today, you can keep digging on that side, I understand that's urgent for you and I will investigate more tonight when I am back.

Answer (score 2):

This should be a bug of viewer to handle new NavisWorks manifest with “modelDerivativeV2” API, I have already logged internally. Late last year, the Navisworks translation was improved to support multiple viewpoints, but unfortunately, it seems the viewer does not support that new manifest well with "modelDerivativeV2" API.

Here is a the reason of the issue and the workaround.

Why this happen? The issue happens because the extract app specify the endpoint API as "modelDerivativeV2" at the function loadModel() of file //views/explore.ejs , and this will use the endpoint of "***/modelderivative/v2/designdata/:urn/manifest***" to get the endpoint, unfortunately, the result seems different from the default internal endpoint, the order of the new Navisworks file manifest is not correct which will make the viewer failed to find any viewable.

How to fix? The simple workaround for you is to just remove the specified parameter "modelDerivativeV2" as follow, it works fine at my side.

Btw, the .Net extract sample works good for Navisworks file on my side.

```html
if ( Autodesk.Viewing.endpoint && Autodesk.Viewing.endpoint.setEndpointAndApi )
    Autodesk.Viewing.endpoint.setEndpointAndApi (window.location.origin + '/forge-proxy') ;
else if ( Autodesk.Viewing.setApiEndpoint )
    Autodesk.Viewing.setApiEndpoint (window.location.origin + '/forge-proxy') ;
else if ( Autodesk.Viewing.setEndpointAndApi )
    Autodesk.Viewing.setEndpointAndApi (window.location.origin + '/forge-proxy') ;
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont u try the translation API ?! ...u can easily Translate (extract) the file in your own server...

Comment: Well we do use the derivatives API, but we need it for offline rendering (which is not officially supported), and I just now learned how to do that by reading the blog. Anyway we are trying to go both ways, using the AD demo extractor in the meanwhile and figuring out how to download offline files using our own implementation